# How can I return the number of count function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to test if my query returns `1` or `0` (so if there is a key matching the one entered)

Here's my code :

```
 $key=$_POST['key'];
 $queryKey = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `smf_invites` WHERE `key` = '$key'");
 $query = mysql_num_rows($queryKey);

 if( !empty ($key))
 {
    echo 'You have entered a key';
    if (!empty ($query))
    {
        echo 'A key is corresponding';
    }

 }
```

EDIT : 
$connect = new mysqli("XXX","XXX","XXX","smf");

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Connection failed : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo 'Connected to database';
}
$key=$_POST['key'];
if( !empty ($key))
{
 echo 'You have entered a key';
 $key = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['key']);
 $queryKey = mysqli_query("SELECT 1 FROM `smf_invites` WHERE `key` =   '$key'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($queryKey))
{
    echo 'A key is corresponding';
}
}
else
{
    echo 'No keys entered';
}
```

Now my code is giving me errors like

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\registration.php on line 32

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\registration.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\registration.php on line 34
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Hint: if numrows is more than nothing...

Comment: Depending on how `key` is generated, you have MySQL injection vulnerabilities. Please instead use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Using `mysqli_` on its own doesn't safeguard against injection. `mysqli` with prepared statements does. ;-)

Comment: @Rameleu which MySQL API are you using to connect with and how? You need to precise that.

Comment: I've changed everything to work with mysqli. I've tested my connection and it's perfectly connected to my database.

Comment: If you're using `mysqli_` and `mysql_` together, that won't work. Use the same API for everything and don't mix them. That's why the answer John gave you, is throwing that error. "resource" is your DB connection that doesn't correspond with the rest of your code/functions.

Comment: Yes that's what I've told you, I'm now using mysqli for everything, but it's still not working

Comment: Definite "not working". New errors? Are you passing DB connection to the required functions?

Comment: Now it tells me 
       Connected to databaseYou have entered a key
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\registration.php on line 32

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\registration.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\registration.php on line 34

Comment: **A:** Just as the error says. Pass DB connection to the functions. At this point, I *highly* suggest you post your new code along with the connection code you're using, and replacing credentials with `xxx`. DO NOT overwrite your existing question/code, but marked as **EDIT:** (here is my updated code), under your original question. We will be commenting back and forth otherwise.

Comment: Simple: You need to pass your DB connection variable to those functions.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are meaning.

Comment: I've posted an *complimentary* answer below. If that doesn't work, your query is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In conjunction with John's answer*

As per your newly edited code:

`mysqli_` requires DB connection be passed for functions.

Change:

```
$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['key']);
```

to:

```
$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['key']);
```

or (use the variable `$key` in there instead.)

Then there's:

```
$queryKey = mysqli_query("SELECT 1 FROM `smf_invites` WHERE `key` =   '$key'");
```

to:

```
$queryKey = mysqli_query($connect, 
"SELECT 1 FROM `smf_invites` WHERE `key` =   '$key'") 
or die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

---

Troubleshooting/debugging

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

Plus, `or die(mysqli_error($connect))`

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Alright this answer helped me finding the problem. The query is now recognizing if there is a corresponding key or not. Thank's a lot for your help, I appreciate !

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues with this code

1. If `$_POST['key']` is not set you will get a PHP Notice
2. `` $queryKey = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `smf_invites` WHERE `key` = '$key'"); `` will *always* return one row. So checking for the number of rows returned will not work.

Here is updated code that should resolve your issue.

```
 if( isset($_POST['key']))
 {
    echo 'You have entered a key';
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['key']);
    $queryKey = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM `smf_invites` WHERE `key` = '$key'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($queryKey))
    {
        echo 'A key is corresponding';
    }
 }
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**Your code is also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Thank's for your fast answer. I've got this as the output : Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\registration.php on line 30

Comment: Your query is failing. Use mysql_error() to find out why. Also, have you verified your connection to MySQL was successful?

Answer (score 0):

I created a class for you and an example check this out.

```
<?php
class MyDb {
    protected $link;
    public function __construct() {
        if (!$this->link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password')) {
            echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
            exit;
        }

        if (!mysql_select_db('table_name', $this->link)) {
            echo 'Could not select database';
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function exist($id) {
        if (is_int($id)) {
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM smf_invites WHERE `key` = '$id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->link);
            return  mysql_num_rows($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


$x = $_POST['key'] = 1;

if(!empty($_POST['key'])) {
    $db = new MyDb();
    if($db->exist($x)) {
        echo "exist";
    } else {
        echo "no exist";
    }
}
```